# StorageFile saving in Appliaction Data in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to store **storagefile** instance from **filepicker** to be used later by saving in **ApplicationData** **Conatiner** . But all I found was serialization as only solution. can I store StorageFile object in application data efficiently?

```
 ApplicationDataContainer AppStorageSetting = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

 AppStorageSetting .Values["File"] = storagefile;
```

Comment: How would you expect that to work without serialization?

Answer (score 4):

In *UWP* the best method to remember picked *StorageFiles* is to use [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br207457) or [MostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br207458). You can hold files and folders there and access them by a returned token. The advantage of this method is that it also remembers privileges.

You can store the obtained token in *LocalSettings* and then reuse it to access the file.